# Can i attach a views grid of images in a carousel

Tags: views, javascript

[image]

Hi i'm new to Drupal and this maybe kinda of advance, but how can i achieve a Drupal views of images grid format displayed in a carousel as shown in the image above

Answer (score 1):

## Views Slideshow

You could use the [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module for this. Here is a quote from its project page:

> ... can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View you create.
>
> **Potential uses**:
>
> - News item slideshow (such as the title, image and teaser of the last 5 news articles submitted).
> - The Last X number of X submitted (images, videos, blog entries, forum posts, comments, testimonials, etc.).
> - Rotate any image, based on any filters you can apply in views.
> - Hottest new products for any ecommerce drupal site.
> - Rotate contact links, share links, etc.
> - You could rotate entire nodes, categories, image galleries, etc. I wouldn't suggest it, but you have that power.
> - It's also a great space saver. Places where you had multiple images or multiple items such as RSS feeds or category listings can now be presented in a slideshow.
>
> The possibilities are really endless, as the more ways you can think of to categorize and add to views, the more you can rotate.

#### Further enhancements

Possibly you may want to further extended this with related modules  (there are dozens of modules to further enhance views) such as [Views Slideshow: Galleria](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_galleria). Here is a quote from that module's project page:

> Integrating Galleria with Views Slideshow.
>
> [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/) is a JavaScript image gallery framework built on top of the jQuery library. The aim is to simplify the process of creating professional image galleries for the web and mobile devices.

## jCarousel

Another option is to consider the [jCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> ... This module allows developers and themers to make use of the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) jQuery plugin. It includes a developer API that other modules can use, as well as Views integration in the 2.0 version so that you can turn any list of content or images into a carousel.
>
> **Features**:
>
> - Built-in Views support.
> - AJAX-loading of additional items as needed.
> - Carousel pager/navigation to jump between multiple pages.
> - Circular wrapping of items.
> - API for direct usage of jCarousel without Views.

Comment: I tried the Views Slideshow module but it not rendering what I want to achieve…A bit more insight I created a grid view of images and text  and I’m wondering if I can use the view I created and import it into the carousel so it can display 9 items in the grid and when I click next it displays another set of items in the grid....any help would be appreciated thank you